# How to solve problem with images "climbing"(overlaying) on one another?

Tags: css, css-grid

When I try to image gallery on trial website using CSS grid, images overlay one another to such extent that is a pain to see.
I tried to check classes and how they interact and everything should be ok. When I delete code of CSS grid, everything starts looking normal, although the sizes of the images are different.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

I would like to make them symmetrical, but don't know what to do. Perhaps, there is an error in managing the sizes of images themselves? But when I tried to make them with the same width and height, nothing changes.

Thank you for help in advance and if there are some inconveniences in post, let me know so I wont do the same mistake in the future.

**Code:**

```css
body {
  margin: auto 0px;
}

.zone {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.zone:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
  -o-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
}


/*Navigation cosumize*/

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navigation {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.end {
  margin-left: auto;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*Cover*/

.red {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60vh;
}


/*Project's grid*/

.for-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(350px, 1fr));
}

img {
  width: 100%
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  padding: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}


/*https://paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-shiny-css-buttons*/


/***********************************************************************
     *  Green Background
     **********************************************************************/

.green {
  background: #56B870;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #56B870), color-stop(100%, #a5c956));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%);
  /* W3C */
}


/***********************************************************************
     *  Red Background
     **********************************************************************/

.red {
  background: #C655BE;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #C655BE), color-stop(100%, #cf0404));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%);
  /* W3C */
}


/***********************************************************************
     *  Yellow Background
     **********************************************************************/

.yellow {
  background: #F3AAAA;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #F3AAAA), color-stop(100%, #febf04));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%);
  /* W3C */
}


/***********************************************************************
     *  Blue Background
     **********************************************************************/

.blue {
  background: #7abcff;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #7abcff), color-stop(44%, #60abf8), color-stop(100%, #4096ee));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%);
  /* W3C */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Layout Master</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="zone green">
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Our team</a>
      </li>
      <li class="end">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
  <div class="zone red">Cover</div>
  <div class="zone blue for-grid">
    <img class="box zone" src="https://i.ibb.co/qWr3CYq/data-storage-2-2.png">
    <img class="box zone" src="https://i.ibb.co/fGcNpN7/desktop-analytics-2.png" alt="product image">
    <img class="box zone" src="https://i.ibb.co/mtXHQ8C/files-2.png" alt="product image">
    <img class="box zone" src="https://i.ibb.co/wyCktLv/monitor-coding-2.png">
    <img class="box zone" src="https://i.ibb.co/M9Qkn6G/monitor-settings-2.png" alt="product image">
    <img class="box zone" src="https://i.ibb.co/k0VNnBN/server-2-2.png" alt="product image">
    <img class="box zone" src="https://i.ibb.co/HKHcrdH/server-3.png" alt="product image">
    <img class="box zone" src="https://i.ibb.co/b7s4NPN/server-safe-2.png" alt="product image">
  </div>
  <div class="zone yellow">Footer</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might want to add some code to your question, that makes it easier to help.

Comment: Sorry,one moment.Got a little distracted.I apologize for inconviniences.

Comment: Hey please replace those local images with live URLs.

Comment: @Manoj Kumar Got it,will be done in a few minutes.

Comment: @Manoj Kumar It's done.Should I learn how to make snippets in the future and apply to my posts?Some other advices how to edit posts?

Comment: Yes, you will learn when asking more on this site. Posting a snippet or a demo is a good way to get an answer. You might also need to check the spelling and grammar a bit. It's a good start for a you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

css

```
.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here is some information about the box model that will help you understand why this might work 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model